# Not able to send time input values in Selenium sendKeys()

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to send input values to an HTML element of `<input type="time">` but can't seem to get the values to be inserted.  Is there a better way to do this?

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

WebElement startTime = driver.findElement(By.id(Constants.startTime)); //'startTime
WebElement endTime = driver.findElement(By.id(Constants.endTime)); //'endTime'

startTime.sendKeys("03:40 AM");
endTime.sendKeys("09:00 PM");
```

Comment: How about a different format, try sending `21:00:00`.

Answer (score 2):

in this you can send start time and end time like this:-

```
startTime.sendKeys("0340AM");
endTime.sendKeys("0900PM");
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to set the value of the input *via JavaScript* in the `HH:MM:SS` format:

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].value = '21:40:00';", endTime);
```

Comment: When the search button is clicked, the value '21:40:00' is sent to the backend rest service, but I need '09:40 PM' to be sent.  How can I make this happen?

Comment: Doing the following worked:

startTime.sendKeys("03");
   startTime.sendKeys("00");
   startTime.sendKeys("AM");
   
   endTime.sendKeys("09");
   endTime.sendKeys("00");
   endTime.sendKeys("PM");

Answer (score 0):

What works for me in Firefox is using ISO format:

```
startTime.sendKeys("08:00:00");
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be related to the fact that you cannot paste in these input elements.
Using actions worked for me:

```
const actions = startTime.getDriver().actions()     
actions.sendKeys(timeString).perform()
```